# SUM function fails when tie exist

Tags: window-functions, sum

[image]

I want to do ABC analysis on this.
As you see, each model has severval partID, each partID has a number of counts.
As you see, the Cum_Counts is wrong when 'ties' exists.

I want to calcute Cumulated counts in each Model.

```
SELECT      
      Model,
      PartID,
      PartDesc,
      Counts,
      SUM(Counts) OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Counts DESC) AS Cum_Counts,
      SUM(Counts) OVER (PARTITION BY Model) AS Total_Counts       
FROM ASL_2
ORDER BY Model
```

Comment: `(... ORDER BY Counts DESC, Pk ASC)` For `Pk` use whatever the Primary key of the table is - or any other unique column you may have.

Comment: thanks james. I may add row number As you suggest. may I ask why my query is not working?

Answer (score 4):

The `SUM() OVER` does not fail, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. When you have an aggregate like `SUM()` with `OVER (... ORDER BY something)`, there is a default `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

This means that the sum goes over all rows that belong to the same partition (same `Model` in this case) and have the `Counts` value greater or equal to the `Counts` value of the current row. In case of ties, you'll see this behaviour.

To resolve ties, you have to include in the `ORDER BY` of the `OVER` part, one or more columns that can, alone or together with `(Model, Counts)`, uniquely identify rows. So the primary key or a unique column is good. If there is a unique constraint on `(Model, PartID)`, you could use `PartID`. The expression would become:

```
SUM(Counts) OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Counts DESC, PartID ASC)
  AS Cumulative_Counts
```

Comment: That is Great solution. I would try it. again. Thanks.